# iphone :- how to get data from xml parser?

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing

i want to get data from xml parser ?
how can i get from xml parser ?
which methods for that and how can i get that ?

any example for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html

Have a look at this..

Answer (score 0):

NSXMLParser calls your "delegate", which has to implement certain methods. When the parser calls your delegate, you grab the data at that time.

For my simple xml file, I just implement the main "Element" one, which only recognizes `<place lat="number" lon="number"...` , and starts like this...

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
                didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
                namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
                qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
                attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
    {
        // we here recognize our one crucial element, "place", and its attributes.
        if([elementName compare:@"place"] == 0)
        {
            OmWayPoint p = {0};

            p.lat = [[attributeDict valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
            p.lon = [[attributeDict valueForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue];
            p.alt = [[attributeDict valueForKey:@"alt"] doubleValue];
            int wpCount = [self addWayPoint:&p];
...
        }
```